# Pandas, how to transform column values from integers to a pre-defined string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe on the form:

```
 Emotion                     Text
0   0   Say , Jim , how about going for a few beers af...
1   0   You know that is tempting but is really not g...
2   0   What do you mean ? It will help us to relax .
3   0   Do you really think so ? I don't . It will ju...
4   0   I guess you are right.But what shall we do ? ...
```

What I want to do is convert the Emotion column based on a dictionary mapping:

EMOTIONS = `{0: neutral, 1: anger, 2: disgust, 3: fear, 4: happiness}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer - [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply)

You can create another column `apply`ing a function to your original column.

```py
>>> emotions_dict = {0: "neutral", 1: "anger", 2: "disgust", 3: "fear", 4: "happiness"}
>>> df["emotions_str"] = df["emotions"].apply(lambda el: emotions_dict[el])
>>> df
   emotions   text emotions_str
0         0    foo      neutral
1         0    bar      neutral
2         0    baz      neutral
3         0  hello      neutral
```

If you want to override your numeric column, you can just replace `emotions_str` with `emotions`.

### [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map)

The same result can be achieved with `map`; the assignment becomes:

```py
>>> df["emotions_str"] = df["emotions"].map(emotions_dict)
```

Values not found in dictionary will be converted to `NaN`.

Comment: I think [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) might be a bit cleaner?

Comment: Thank you, I added that to the answer.